# Why does list.append behave differently in the "for" loop with different levels

Tags: list, for-loop, numpy, append

Why is this happening? Do I have to use the copy of a numpy.array? but
it seems to work with the 1st code. Can not figure out why.

```
import numpy as np

n=3
h_all=[]
h=np.zeros((n,n))

for i in range(0, n):
    h = h + 1.
    h_all.append(h)          
print h_all
```

it gives

> ```
> [array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
> [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
> [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]), array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
> [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
> [ 2.,  2.,  2.]]), array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
> [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
> [ 3.,  3.,  3.]])]
> ```
>
> Which is good
>   but if I code as

```
n=3
h_all=[]
h=np.zeros((n,n))
maxnum=3

for k in range(0, n):
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            h[i,j] = h[i,j] + 1.
    h_all.append(h[:])          
print h_all
```

> ```
> It becomes:
> [array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
> [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
> [ 3.,  3.,  3.]]), array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
> [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
> [ 3.,  3.,  3.]]), array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
> [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
> [ 3.,  3.,  3.]])]
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for k in range(0, n):
    ....
    h_all.append(h[:])
```

puts a pointer to `h` in the `h_all` list.  Since you are modifying `h` at each step in-place, the same pointer is placed in `h_all` each time.  At the end, `h_all` displays the current value of `h` in each slot.

This is a common issue when dealing the Python lists and dictionaries.  You have to append a copy at each step in the iteration, not a mutable object.

To clarify this, look at `id(h_all[0])` and `id(h_all[1])`; I expect they are the same.  Or try `h +=1` after the loop, and watch the values of `h_all` change.

I should add that `h[:]` creates a copy if `h` is a list, but not if it is an array.

Comment: Thanks for the help @hpaulj. Here is the follow up: 

**1** The `id(h_all[0])` and `id(h_all[i])` are not the same (for both codes) 

**2**  `h +=1` does change all `h` in `h_all` for the second code, but does not affect the `h_all` result from the first code. 

**3** In the first code, why h is not acting as a pointer the same way as in the second code?

Comment: I forgot; `h[:]` produces a `view` of an array.  That is a new object, but it shares the underlying data.  So the `id` will differ in each iteration; but the values are shared.  `h.copy()` needs to be used in an iteration like this.